# Change text size of Textbutton in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am new to Libgdx and I have been searching for 3 hours to find a way to change text size in text button but I couldn't find any method for this. What should I do to do this.

```
    Table rootTable = new Table();
    rootTable.setFillParent(true);
    rootTable.setDebug(true, true);

    Table menuTable = new Table();
    rootTable.add(menuTable).expand().center().right();

    Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));

    TextButton singlePlayer = new TextButton("Single Player",skin);
    TextButton multiPlayer = new TextButton("Multi Player", skin);
    TextButton options = new TextButton("Options", skin);
    TextButton exit = new TextButton("Exit", skin);

    int x = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    int unit = x / 6;

    float scale = unit / singlePlayer.getHeight();

    float width = singlePlayer.getWidth() * scale;

    menuTable.add( singlePlayer ).size( width,unit).right().row();
    menuTable.add( multiPlayer ).size( width,unit).right().row();
    menuTable.add( options ).size( width,unit).right().row();
    menuTable.add( exit ).size( width,unit).right().row();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `textButton.getLabel().setFontScale(x, y)`.

Comment: It worked but it looks really bad and blurry :/ isn't there anyway to change size instead of scaling?

Comment: Size and scaling are effectively the same thing when it gets to the screen. You need to start with a higher resolution font texture. And make sure the texture is loaded with mip-mapping on (and use texture filters MipMapLinearLinear, Linear).

Comment: You will need to use a bigger BitmapFont and update the skin JSON file accordingly.

Comment: Use a bigger BitmapFont, then assume a high density device. Then work out a formula to scale down the font on lower density devices using `Gdx.graphics.getDensity()`

Answer (score 2):

Use [FreeTypeFontGenerator](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype) to set a font and then Update the button:

```
private void UpdateButton(float xf, float width, float height) {
    if (xf > grayButton.getX() + grayButton.getWidth() / 2) {
        width += 20;
        height += 20;
    } else {
        width -= 20;
        height -= 20;
    }
    params.size = (int) ((int) width / 4.0);
    fontB = generator.generateFont(params);
    grayButtonStyle.font = fontB;
    grayButton.remove();
    grayButton = new TextButton("abcABC", grayButtonStyle);
    grayButton.setSize(width, height);
    grayButton.setPosition((screenWidth - width) / 2, (screenHeight - height) / 2);
    grayButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            UpdateButton(Gdx.input.getX(), grayButton.getWidth(), grayButton.getHeight());
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(grayButton);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it slow to generate fonts on the go? Also can you explain what does UpdateButton function do? So I can mark your answer as accepted.